# API Call for arranging icons on desktop

Tags: winapi

Are there any calls for arranging icon by name, size, etc or `'Align to grid'`?

Comment: You're going to get a lot of "Don't re-arrange users desktop icons" type comments, so you should cut them off and explain why you want to do this.  I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think there is an API for this.  Doing some searching for "arrange desktop icons programmatically" yields some registry hacks and hacks involving sending window messages to the desktop window... nothing clean.

Comment: Sending window messages to the desktop window is cleane enough, actually.

Comment: @jeffamaphone I'm not sure why the asker wished to do that, but I was searching for a solution to do the same because I use my laptop with an external monitor and found that every time it (the external monitor) is turned off (even by windows power management), all my icons go "wandering" on the desktop, so I wish to create an application which sends them back to their places.

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried this, but if I had to I would first try sending [LVM_ARRANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774884(VS.85).aspx) message to the desktop window. And [LVM_SORTITEMS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761227(VS.85).aspx)/[LVM_SORTITEMSEX](http://LVM_SORTITEMSEX) might help with the sorting.

For the auto arrange you could try modify the style and using [LVS_AUTOARRANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774739(VS.85).aspx) style or the [extended styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774732(VS.85).aspx) .

So you will need to use something like [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499(VS.85).aspx) to get the desktop windows and then use [SetWindowLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591(VS.85).aspx) with GWL_STYLE/GWL_EXSTYLE to modify the window style bits.